# How to display selected text from tree structure using HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a problem that bothers me for a long time. I didn't found a solution so some help would be more than welcome.

I don't know how to display selected text in html. I have a tree structure, and wheen i choose an option (text) from that tree structure, that text must be shown in box on right side. Picture below shows what is my problem and what my sollution must be.

I have two tags: Tag 1 and Tag 2, each tag has the same tree structure. When i choose: Tag1 -> Antarctica and Tag2->Asia->Southern-West->India, this two selections must be shown in the box on right side. Look at the picture.

Picture:
http://postimg.org/image/vptxlzn8l/

Code that i have so far is:

```
    <!-- Header -->
            <h1 style="padding-left:45%"> SELECTION </h1> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="container responsive-tabs-default">
        <ul class="responsive-tabs">
            <li><a href="#example-1-tab-1" target="_self">Tag 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#example-1-tab-2" target="_self">Tag 2 </a></li>   
        </ul>

        <div class="responsive-tabs-content bm-larger">
            <div id="example-1-tab-1" class="responsive-tabs-panel">

                    <!-- TREE BEGIN-->

                    <h1>Naslov</h1>
                        <!--  <input type="search" id="my-search" placeholder="search"> -->
                        <ul id="my-tree1">
                            <li>
                                <div>Asia</div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>Southern-West</div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><div>India</div></li>
                                            <li><div>Pakistan</div></li>
                                            <li><div>Butan</div></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><div>Southern-East</div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><div>Indonesia</div></li>
                                            <li><div>Vietnam</div></li>
                                            <li><div>malaysia</div></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><div>Far-east</div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><div>China</div></li>
                                            <li><div>North Korea</div></li>
                                            <li><div>South Korea</div></li>
                                            <li><div>Japan</div></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><div>Central</div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><div>Mongol</div></li>
                                            <li><div>kazakhstan</div></li>
                                            <li><div>kyrgyzstan</div></li>
                                        </ul>                       
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><div>Antarctica</div></li>
                            <li>
                                <div>Africa</div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><div>Moroco</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Egypt</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Ghana</div></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>Europe</div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><div>United Kingdom</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Sweden</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Germany</div></li>
                                    <li><div>France</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Spain</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Italy</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Austria</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Turkey</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Russia</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Denmark</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Finland</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Iceland</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Switzerland</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Hungary</div></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul> 
                    <!-- TREE END-->
            </div>
            <div id="example-1-tab-2" class="responsive-tabs-panel">

                <h1>Naslov</h1>
                    <!--  <input type="search" id="my-search" placeholder="search"> -->
                    <ul id="my-tree2">
                        <li>
                            <div>Asia</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div>Southern-West</div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><div>India</div></li>
                                        <li><div>Pakistan</div></li>
                                        <li><div>Butan</div></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><div>Southern-East</div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><div>Indonesia</div></li>
                                        <li><div>Vietnam</div></li>
                                        <li><div>malaysia</div></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><div>Far-east</div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><div>China</div></li>
                                        <li><div>North Korea</div></li>
                                        <li><div>South Korea</div></li>
                                        <li><div>Japan</div></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><div>Central</div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><div>Mongol</div></li>
                                        <li><div>kazakhstan</div></li>
                                        <li><div>kyrgyzstan</div></li>
                                    </ul>                       
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><div>Antarctica</div></li>
                        <li>
                            <div>Africa</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><div>Moroco</div></li>
                                <li><div>Egypt</div></li>
                                <li><div>Ghana</div></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div>Europe</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><div>United Kingdom</div></li>
                                <li><div>Sweden</div></li>
                                <li><div>Germany</div></li>
                                <li><div>France</div></li>
                                <li><div>Spain</div></li>
                                <li><div>Italy</div></li>
                                <li><div>Austria</div></li>
                                <li><div>Turkey</div></li>
                                <li><div>Russia</div></li>
                                <li><div>Denmark</div></li>
                                <li><div>Finland</div></li>
                                <li><div>Iceland</div></li>
                                <li><div>Switzerland</div></li>
                                <li><div>Hungary</div></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul> 
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">       
        <div class="container2" > 
            <ul class="responsive-tabs">
                <h3>You have choosen:</h3>
                <button type="button">Delete choosen data</button>
                <hr>    
            </ul>   
            <p> 

                     HERE MUST BE THE SELECTED TEXT FROM TREE STRUCTURE

            </p>        
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- Footer --> 

<!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tabs/js/smoothscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="tabs/js/backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="tabs/js/responsive-tabs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- tree begin -->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tree/jquery.treefilter.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var tree = new treefilter($("#my-tree1"), {
            searcher : $("input#my-search"),
            multiselect : false });
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var tree = new treefilter($("#my-tree2"), {
            searcher : $("input#my-search"),
            multiselect : false });
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        var tree = new treefilter($("#my-tree3"), {
            searcher : $("input#my-search"),
            multiselect : false });
    });

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.tree = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
<!-- tree end -->
</table>
```

Now i need a piece of code which will solve my problem: write the selected text from tree structure in the box on right side. Can anyone please help me?

Thank you for helping me.

Klemen

Comment: This one more picture of my code from right click on page and "Check the element" : http://postimg.org/image/u8rec19el/

When Tag is open  the  <li class="active"> etc. Please check on picture

Comment: can you create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 1):

use jquery .parents() function and look through the parent elements and create new tree

on clicked element $(this).parents()

Comment: I didn' found any way how to build new tree. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DIVs, java script & the button onClick property to achieve this.
Details here:
http://blogs.html5andcss3.org/show-and-hide-div-with-javascript/

Comment: This only shows how to hide some rows or DIVs. I need the solutiont that wil show me selected text from tree structure into the box on right side not in the same box as tree structure is. And jus don't know how to pick up a selected text and show it in another part of page in this case in the box on right side of the page. Selecteds text and all previous steps of tree structure must be shown.

Comment: You could put the box on the right inside a DIV and use onClick property on elements of the tree.